# bake form in spring mvc for edit

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

total beginner to spring mvc.
I need to prepopulate edit form in springmvc frame-work.

contact_edit.jsp

```
<form:form method="post" action="edit/1" commandName="contact">
<% Contact contact = (Contact)request.getAttribute("contact");  %>
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="firstname">
                    <spring:message code="label.firstname" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstname" value="<%=contact.getFirstname() %>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastname">
                    <spring:message code="label.lastname" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastname" value="<%=contact.getLastname() %>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="email">
                    <spring:message code="label.email" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email" value="<%=contact.getEmail()%>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="telephone">
                    <spring:message code="label.telephone" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="telephone" value="<%=contact.getTelephone()%>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"
                value="<spring:message code="label.addcontact"/>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

controller code to get this page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{contactId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable("contactId") Integer contactId,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("I was here");
    Contact contact = contactService.getContact(contactId);
    request.setAttribute("contact", contact);
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashedMap();
    model.put("contact", contact);

    return new ModelAndView("contact_edit", model);
}
```

My exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'firstname' of bean class [net.viralpatel.contact.form.Contact_$$_javassist_0]: Getter for property 'firstname' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:845)
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:721)
org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:219)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:320)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspService(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:147)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:761)
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:721)
org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:219)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:320)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspService(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:147)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

My Contact Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CONTACTS")
public class Contact {

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
private String firstname;

@Column(name="LASTNAME")
private String lastname;

@Column(name="EMAIL")
private String email;

@Column(name="TELEPHONE")
private String telephone;


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public String getTelephone() {
    return telephone;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
    this.telephone = telephone;
}
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

My Contact class contains all getters and setters method , even my create form is working fine. Can't figure out what is creating problem where . I have already inserted contact object in request as well as in ModelAndView class. !!!??!!

Comment: could you post your Contact model class?

Comment: I have added Contact Class ..kindly let me know if anything else needed. And I repeat getters and setters are perfect as create is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, by initializing sessionFactory in applicationContext.xml instead of spring-servlet.xml. And make sure to remove it from spring-servlet.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your model class. Do you have getter/setter methods for `firstname` in your model ? If yes, please add the code for us investigate more

Comment: getters are already there ...I have edited my post .. can you please check

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to invoke the getters explicitly. since you are using the spring form tags, spring will automatically populate your form.

edit:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{contactId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable("contactId") Integer contactId) {
    System.out.println("I was here");
    Contact contact = contactService.getContact(contactId);
    return new ModelAndView("contact_edit","contact", contact);
}
```

please try to replace this line

```
Contact contact = contactService.getContact(contactId);
```

with

```
Contact contact = new Contact();
```

just to figure out where the problem has its roots

Comment: getters are already there ...I have edited my post .. can you please check

Answer (score 0):

Few things to correct in your code:

1) When you add your domain objects to model, spring mvc makes them available to your JSPs. You don't need to again set the domain object in the request. 
So, remove following from your controller.

`request.setAttribute("contact", contact);`

and similarly no need to refer request object in your jsp. so remove

`Contact contact = (Contact)request.getAttribute("contact");`

2) When you set form-backing domain object using 'commandName' attribute of spring's form tag,  spring uses the domain object's properties to set/get values for the form elements.

For example, in the following code spring will use getter/setter for contact's firstname property while populating/submitting the form.

```
<form:form method="post" action="edit/1" commandName="contact">
    <form:input path="firstname"/>
</form>
```

Just make sure that getter/setter are implemented for all the properties that you need to use from a domain/ form baking object.

Comment: getters are already there ...I have edited my post .. can you please check

Comment: As I mentioned in my response, remove the unwanted code (setting and reading object from request) both from controller and jsps, and try it again. And if that doesn't work, please post your create contact controller method